# Perl match in context

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I would like to find a word in a text file, and save it to a variable along with some characters. for example in the text file it would be something like:

Isoelectric Point = 6.2505

I'll be looping through a directory of files, so the value of the Isoelectric Point will change, and that is why I need the characters after the match to be saved to a variable.

Comment: [http://whathaveyoutried.com](What  have  you  tried  yet) ?

Comment: I've just been mucking around with the matching operator, I'm fairly new to regex

Answer (score 1):

```
if (my ($point) = $str =~ /Isoelectric Point = (\S+)/) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does the (\S+) do?

Comment: `\S is a negated \s; it represents any non-whitespace character`. You should have a look at [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html)

Comment: for the value of $point i got a 1, when I would be hoping for Isoelectric Point = 6.2505

Comment: That's because you didn't use the code I posted. Quite possibly, you removed the parens that caused the regex match to be evaluated in list context.